# Move sprite on a background along a grid in sprite kit?

Tags: scroll, grid, sprite, sprite-kit

How can I drag and move sprites with touch in sprite kit but in a grid manner? I can already move them on touch, but I need to simulate a tiledmap...

Answer (score 0):

Override the method in your SKScene:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

Then when you receive messages in this, just check the position with:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if(touch){//
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    .. moving code here
}
```

Once you have your position, just move it based upon which grid item the touch is currently within:

```
//Grid of 20x20 pixels, with entire grid starting at 0,0
static const CGFloat GridSize = 20;

int gridColumn = (int)(location.x/GridSize); //we can lose the precision here
int gridRow = (int)(location.y/GridSize); //we can lose the precision here

node.position = CGPointMake(gridColumn*GridSize, gridRow*GridSize);
```

Of course you could animate the move with an SKAction, but if you're tracking a touch, you probably want it in realtime.